# Invalid constant after fixup?

Tags: assembly, arm, immediate-operand

For some reason, when I try to compile this bit of code, the compiler says `syscall.s:72:invalid constant (0x172) after fixup`:

```
.globl _mach_msg_trap$MACH
_mach_msg_trap$MACH:
    stmfd sp!, {r4,r7}
    mov r7, #370 /* this is line 72 */
    svc 0
    ldmfd sp!, {r4, r7}
    bx lr
```

I don't know why it's doing it. When I put a smaller constant into `r7`, it works fine. But with higher numbers, it spits out this error. I've temporary fixed it by doing `mov r7, #300` and `add r7, #70`, which achieves the desired effect. Still not sure what caused the error though.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The ARM Instruction Set, up to ARMv5, is only able to use a limited range of immediate values. The problem is that the value has to be encoded in the instruction itself. As all ARM Instructions are 32-bit wide, the original instruction-set up to ARMv5 only had a total of 8+4 bits to encode immediates. With the first 8-bit being able to load any 8-bit value in the range of 0-255 and the 4 bit being a right rotate in steps of 2 between 0 and 30.

So you can load values like:

```
#0
#122
#121 ror #24 = 30976
#230 ror #12 = 241172480
```

But, #370 is not loadable with this scheme, it would require something like `#185 ror #31` which is not possible.

**There are two ways to get your immediate value loaded.**

1. How you already solved it by constructing the value in multiple steps.
2. By loading the value from memory with ldr: **`ldr r7,=#370`** The assembler then will create a constant-pool and load the value from there via pc-relative addressing.

Usually you should prefer to construct constants with up to 2 instructions, if thats not possible (or the value has to be relocatable) use ldr.

Starting with ARMv7 you can also use **`movw` to load any 16 bit value** in the lower half of a register while zeroing the top-half and `movt` to load another 16bit value to the upper half without touching the lower half.

Comment: I have the same problem, but using armv4. I want to load 0x0000ffff in a register. movw and movt are not supported in this arm mode. And I can't either use ldr r3, =#0000ffff

Comment: You have to load ldr r3, =#0x0000ffff not =#0000ffff. The fixup is down by the assembler. You can also just mov r3, #255 - orr r3,r3, #65280

Comment: I can't put that value in the register. It's not a direction, it's a constant I want to store in memory, in a position given by v1 variable (in C the instruction is: iowrite32(v1, 0x0000FFFF). The message is:                                                      Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 0000ffff

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what exactly you want to do there, please write up a complete question about that on SO. Comments are not meant for that kind of discussion but only to further the actual answer or question they are attached to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782510/this-assembly-code-makes-nothing   This is my question. Where it says edited, I explain the problem with iowrite32. Thanks

Comment: This rotated-8-bit immediate encoding isn't unique to `mov` is it?  Or does `and reg, reg, #imm` have different limitations?  Your first sentence doesn't need to be so specific, and could make this a better duplicate target for questions like [Invalid constant after fixup (and mask)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63038207) where the not-encodeable instruction was something other than `mov`.