# ARM assembly error - invalid constant after fixup

Tags: assembly, arm

I know this question has been asked before so sorry to ask again but I have no clue how to fix it. At the start of my program I try to move binary value 101000110000100110000 into R0 but I get the error message "Error: invalid constant (146130) after fixup"

```
        .global _start
_start: 
    mov R0,#0b101000110000100110000
    bl  correct16
    mov R7,#1
    svc 0

correct16:
    push    {R1-R10}
```

I don't really understand why it is doing this or how to fix it because I have never had this error before.

Comment: Consult an instruction set reference, in particular the allowed range of immediates for a `mov`. TL;DR: use `ldr r0, =0b101000110000100110000` PS: next time specify which assembler you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid constant after fixup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261300/invalid-constant-after-fixup)

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to use an immediate value of 0x146130, the `mov` instruction can take an immediate up to 16 bits (though this depends on your architecture and instruction set), so what you're attempting to do can't be encoded. You can load a 16 bit immediate, and add the rest in, or use a literal pool to solve it.

```
_start: 
    mov R0,#0x6130       
    movt R0,#0x14
    bl  correct16
    mov R7,#1
    svc 0
```

This loads the bottom halfword into r0, then loads in the top halfword afterwards.